# More than one column back in linq when using Take 1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

So I have a table that has stats for workouts in that table there two fields Feet and Inches. I work out the longest jump by going to linq like this.

```
var playerBroadJumpHistory = await api.GetAllWorkOutsByPlayerId(playerId);
var maxBroadJumpFeet = (from u in playerBroadJumpHistory
                        where u.PlayerId == playerId
                        orderby u.BroadJumpFeet descending
                        select u).Take(1);
```

But I also want to get the value of inches which is u.BroadJumpInches how would I do that in the above example but retain both elements?. I am obviously doing this to get the max distance the person jumped over there scores but I need both columns of data so can display them.

Could I just create a new object using the select ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should be multiple columns that is u.BroadJumpFeet, u.BroadJumpInches

```
var maxBroadJumpFeet = (from u in playerBroadJumpHistory
                        where u.PlayerId == playerId
                        orderby u.BroadJumpFeet, u.BroadJumpInches  descending
                        select new {Feet = u.BroadJumpFeet, 
                       Inches =u.BroadJumpInches}).Take(1);
```

Comment: Actualy this is not copy-paste. He added two columns in orderby `orderby u.BroadJumpFeet, u.BroadJumpInches  descending`. But this code would return min BroadJumpFeet result with max BroadJumpInches  (because if you miss `descending` keyword than compiler assume that you want `ascending` by default). And `orderby u.BroadJumpFeet descending, u.BroadJumpInches descending` would be a correct answer (I wrote separate answer for your question with more details).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out what I nedded to do was this.

```
var maxBroadJumpFeet = (from u in playerBroadJumpHistory
                        where u.PlayerId == playerId
                        orderby u.BroadJumpFeet descending
                        select new {Feet = u.BroadJumpFeet, 
                       Inches =u.BroadJumpInches}).Take(1);
```

Simply declaring a new object was enough.

But what if I wanted both columns to be included in the max for example if it was 5FT6 and 5FT3 obv I want it return 5FT6

Answer (score 0):

If you want both columns to be included in the max, than you should sort both columns in descending way `orderby u.BroadJumpFeet descending, u.BroadJumpInches descending` Something like this

```
var maxBroadJumpFeet = (
        from u in playerBroadJumpHistory
        where u.PlayerId == playerId
        orderby u.BroadJumpFeet descending, u.BroadJumpInches descending
        select new { Feet = u.BroadJumpFeet, Inches = u.BroadJumpInches }
    ).Take(1);
```

By the way if you want to retrieve a result as an object instance (not an Enumerable), than you can do

```
var maxBroadJumpFeet = (
            from u in playerBroadJumpHistory
            where u.PlayerId == playerId
            orderby u.BroadJumpFeet descending, u.BroadJumpInches descending
            select new { Feet = u.BroadJumpFeet, Inches = u.BroadJumpInches }
        ).FirstOrDefault();
```

It will return max result or null (if no element in a query with PlayerId == playerId restriction)

Also `select u` or `select new { Feet = u.BroadJumpFeet, Inches = u.BroadJumpInches }` do not affect on "max logic", it is only affect on what object you would receive at the end.